# Canvas is not getting aligned correctly

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

i am trying to make a chat app using kivy and kivymd but I have faced a problem. I am trying to place a canvas before a label widget but it is not getting aligned correctly. Please help me fix this issue.

***Kivy code***

```
<ChatScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'My Room'
            anchor_title: 'center'
            left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: x]]
            right_action_items: [['logout-variant', lambda x:x]]
        ScrollView:
            BoxLayout:
                id: chat_area
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: 1, 1
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0,0,0,0.2
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
        Widget:
            id: separator
            size_hint: 1, 0.008
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0,0,0,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: 0, separator.center_y
                    size: separator.width, 1.5
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            TextInput:
                id: msg
                hint_text: 'Enter Message'
                background_color: 0,0,0,0  
                foreground_color: 0,0,0,1
            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'send'
                on_press: root.send_msg()
```

***Python code***

```
class ChatScreen(Screen):
    def send_msg(self):
        msg = self.ids.msg.text
        if msg=='':
            pass
        else:
            label = MDLabel(
                text=msg,
                size_hint=(0.3, 1),
                pos_hint={'center_x': 0.7, 'center_y': 0.5}
                )
            with label.canvas.before:
                Color(0,1,0,0.7)
                RoundedRectangle(radius=[30,30,30,30], size=label.size, pos=label.pos)
            self.ids.chat_area.add_widget(label)
            self.ids.msg.text = ''
```

The canvas of the label which is being added on button click, is stacking over each other.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your `RoundedRectangle` is not at the correct position is that the position and size are being set when you create the `MDLabel`, so it uses the default values of `(0,0)` and `(100,100)`.

You can take advantage of the  automatic bindings that kivy gives you by defining a class for the messages. Perhaps like this:

```
class ChatMessage(MDLabel):
    pass
```

Then add a rule for that class in the `kv`:

```
<ChatMessage>:
    size_hint: (0.3, 1)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.7, 'center_y': 0.5}
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0,1,0,0.7)
        RoundedRectangle:
            radius: [30,30,30,30]
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

And use the new class in your `send_msg()` method:

```
class ChatScreen(Screen):
    def send_msg(self):
        msg = self.ids.msg.text
        if msg=='':
            pass
        else:
            label = ChatMessage(text=msg)
            self.ids.chat_area.add_widget(label)
            self.ids.msg.text = ''
```

Now the `RoundedRectangle` will automatically be adjusted to the size and position of the `ChatMessage`.